# How to fix this Android Studio editor font on dialogs on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio-2.1

I'am using ubuntu 16 Gnome 3.18 and I've installed Android Studio to develop my projects but when I go to any dialog of Android Studio like when you want to rename a class or activity or whatever it appears to me like this: [image]

Someone had the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Solved it with changing font to Ubuntu mono, from the default one.
You can do that simply by going:
*Configure -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance*, then you check box "Override default fonts by ():", and choose font that best suits you.